# Why Apache blocks itself from listening to port 8080?

Tags: networking, apache-http-server

As you can see in the image if you enlarge it, when I run httpd.exe apache says it cannot bind to address 8080. Thing is, the reason apache cannot bind to address 8080 is because apache IS the one listening to address 8080. The PID of the program that listens to 8080 is of `wampapache64`.

Every time I try to change ports this happens, and it prevents me from setting up virtual hosts for my websites.
[image]

Comment: Can you please rephrase this as a question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. From the look's of it you are trying to start the apache process manually since it's already running, probably as service. When you make configuration changes you should restart the apache service. Press start and R keys together, then type services.msc and hit enter. Locate and restart the apache service.

Comment: httpd can be restarted via a flag (e.g. `httpd -k restart`). However, has installed some sort of WAMP package. There may be {reasons} that he should restart via the windows services applet (such as install-specific config locations/startup flags)